# Ninject: Binding an interface with a generic that is also an interface

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, interface, ninject-2

I have searched this issue but with no luck. Here we go.

Suppose I have an interface:

```
interface IQueryRepository<T> where T : class
```

and I want to bind any requests for:

```
IQueryRepository<IClient>
```

to:

```
ConcreteQueryRepository<Client>
```

I've tried the obvious:

```
Bind<IGenericQueryRepository<IClient>>().To<ConcreteQueryRepository<Client>>()
```

But I get an error:

> `ConcreteQueryRepository<Client>` cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in 
>       the generic type or method '`Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax<T>.To<TImplementation>()`'
>       There is no implicit reference conversion from '`ConcreteQueryRepository<Client>`'
>       to '`IGenericQueryRepository<IClient>`'

But I don't understand why since GenericQueryRepository implements IGenericQueryRepository and Client implements IClient.

I would like Ninject to give me a concrete generic repository where T is Client. I want this to avoid using concrete types in the code.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

In your question you mentioned the following:

> ... GenericQueryRepository implements IGenericQueryRepository and Client implements IClient.

Let's make it simpler by using fruits: Fruit implements IFruit. We'll also create a Tree class.

```
public interface IFruit { }
public class Fruit : IFruit { }
public class Tree<T> where T : IFruit { }

Tree<IFruit> tree = new Tree<Fruit>() // error
```

This will reproduce the same kind of error you're experiencing. Why? Simple.

Though Fruit implements IFruit, an Fruit Tree doesn't implement a IFruit Tree. There is no cast possible between the Fruit Tree and the IFruit Tree, although you would expect it. They are both Trees, but with a **different** type parameter. The fact that their type parameters are related to each other, doesn't matter.

In other words: there is no cast possible between the Fruit Tree and the IFruit Tree, because their type parameters don't match.

In general, when casting with generics, make sure their type parameters **match**. However, there are a few exceptional cases. See [Variance in Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx).

In your case, you could fix it by using IClient as type parameter for the GenericQueryRepository class. Doing this will allow casting because the type parameters match. But I don't know your application architecture, so this fix might be inapplicable in your case.

---

**EDIT**: To make it easier to understand, copy paste the code below and see what the compiler says.

```
interface IFruit { }
class Fruit : IFruit { }
interface ITree<T> where T : IFruit { }
class Tree<T> : ITree<T> where T : IFruit { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITree<Fruit> test1 = new Tree<Fruit>();   // compiles: type parameters match
        ITree<IFruit> test2 = new Tree<Fruit>();  // fails:    type parameters don't match
        ITree<Fruit> test3 = new Tree<IFruit>();  // fails:    type parameters don't match
        ITree<IFruit> test4 = new Tree<IFruit>(); // compiles: type parameters match

        IEnumerable<IFruit> test5 = new List<Fruit>(); // compiles: this is one of the exceptional cases
    }
}
```

That should clear things up about what is and what is not possible.

Comment: I did try to use `IClient` as parameter and the result was that Ninject served a `Dictionary<IClient>` to Dapper (a db-object mapper) which crashed with an exception "...requires a parameterless default constructor". I inspected the type received by Dapper and it was an interface, thus no constructor. I don't know the internals of Dapper, but I know it uses reflection. Thus, that is not a solution for me because Dapper tries to instantiate the generic type `T` on runtime which would require the `new()` constraint. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me

Comment: @hlintrup and what if you try to use `Client` as both type parameters? Thus using `IClient` nowhere. That should fix your current exception, since `Client` does have a constructor.

Comment: Yes, that works and it is what I ended up doing. I guess its okay since Client is just a POCO that is a 1:1 mapping to a database table row. The real use of DI is with behavioral entities and testing, not with POCOs.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when trying to bind a Dapper query to an interface type, thinking about it, it seems to make sense that Dapper can't instantiate an Interface type.

The interface is only a contract and does not know about how to instantiate a concrete implementation of it.

Dapper needs a type that is concrete implementation of the interface type  otherwise Dapper would also have to know which concrete implementation of the interface to instantiate, and in that case Dapper would behave like a DI container which, indeed, it isn't.